# Prevent duplication in this Insert command

Tags: c#, validation, compare

```
private void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (idTextBox.Text != "" & nameTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into item_details (id, Name, MFD, EXP, QTY, damaged, MP, CP) values ('" + idTextBox.Text + "','" + nameTextBox.Text + "','" + MFDTextBox.Text + "','" + EXPTextBox.Text + "','" + QTYTextBox.Text + "','" + damagedTextBox.Text + "','" + MPTextBox.Text + "','" + CPTextBox.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Clone();
        MessageBox.Show("record inserted");
        conn.Close();
    }
    Admin_welcome newChild = new Admin_welcome();
    newChild.MdiParent = MdiParent;
    newChild.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Comment: Try to ask a more direct question. What kind of problem are you having? How have you tried to solve it? What specific thing would you like help with. For example, "I'm getting duplicate items in my `item_details` table - can anyone suggest how I could avoid that?".

Comment: This `idTextBox.Text != "" & nameTextBox.Text != ""` should be `idTextBox.Text != "" && nameTextBox.Text != ""`

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say few things here,

First of all, you need to set a criteria for considering a record duplicate - i.e. duplicate name or duplicate name and MFD, Expiry etc. Once you are done, you will first have to make a select query with matching criteria and if you find a matching record, you are going to insert a duplicate so you should not insert it and show the error.

Secondly, your code is prone to sql injection. I would recommend that you use a stored procedure and sqlparameters to make sure that the code is safe. You could also embed the procedure of checking for duplicates in the stored procedure itself.